# How to decript salt

Tags: passwords, password-encryption

I'm made one register and loggin form and code.
its ok. I encript my passwords like this:

```
public static function Hash($password) {
    $hash = "f6e649b8fc4c9e35eda6969660e36a2e";
    $crypt = md5($password . ($hash));

    return $crypt;
}
```

Why i do to decrypt this?
Thankyou;

Comment: You are not encrypting anything, you are hashing. And hashes are supposed to be irreversible.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very unsafe way to hash a password. The salt is static, so it cannot not fullfill its purpose and MD5 is ways too fast for hashing passwords (one can brute-force about [100 Giga MD5 per second](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#performance) with common hardware).

PHP offers an easy and safe method [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to hash passwords, which handles all the tricky parts like generating a safe salt:

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```